# Replace value by null in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Given a Polars DataFrame, is there a way to replace a particular value by "null"? For example, if there's a sentinel value like `"_UNKNOWN"` and I want to make it truly missing in the dataframe instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Update]:**
[`Expr.replace()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html#polars.Expr.replace) is now the idiomatic way to do this <sup>(see also [@asterix's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77682739/))</sup>

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).replace("_UNKNOWN", None))
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B    ┆ C   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a    ┆ null ┆ 1   │
│ b    ┆ d    ┆ 2   │
│ null ┆ e    ┆ 3   │
│ c    ┆ f    ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

---

You can use `.when().then().otherwise()`

`pl.col(pl.Utf8)` is used to select all "string columns".

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "_UNKNOWN", "c"], 
   "B": ["_UNKNOWN", "d", "e", "f"], 
   "C": [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col(pl.Utf8) == "_UNKNOWN")
     .then(None)
     .otherwise(pl.col(pl.Utf8)) # keep original value
     .name.keep()
)
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Would be great to include @Dean's tweak in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is really a tweak of @jqurious's answer.

When you do a `when` and your condition isn't met then the default is `null` so you can just do:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col(pl.Utf8) != "_UNKNOWN")
        .then(pl.col(pl.Utf8)) # keep original value
        .keep_name()
)
```

If you have multiple null conditions say `null_strings=["_UNKNOWN", "UNK", "who_knows"]` then you can use a `is_in` like this:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(~pl.col(pl.Utf8).is_in(null_strings))
        .then(pl.col(pl.Utf8)) # keep original value
        .keep_name()
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to previous answers, if you have just imported dataset, you can specify what values will be `null`

Example `data.csv`:

```
A,B
a,1
b,2
_UNKNOWN,more than 3
c,_UNKNOWN
```

when importing dataset:

```
pl.read_csv("data.csv",
            null_values="_UNKNOWN",
            # infer_schema_length=0,  # optional (if you will get parsing error))
```

`df`:

```
┌──────┬─────────────┐
│ A    ┆ B           │
│ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ str  ┆ str         │
╞══════╪═════════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b    ┆ 2           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ more than 3 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c    ┆ null        │
└──────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

[`replace`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html)(introduced in v0.19.16, aka `map_dict`) is all you need!

```py
print(
    pl.DataFrame({
       "A": ["a", "b", "_UNKNOWN", "c"], 
       "B": ["_UNKNOWN", "d", "e", "f"], 
       "C": [1, 2, 3, 4]})
    .with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).replace({"_UNKNOWN": None}))
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B    ┆ C   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a    ┆ null ┆ 1   │
│ b    ┆ d    ┆ 2   │
│ null ┆ e    ┆ 3   │
│ c    ┆ f    ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘
```